# How can I convert a CImg image to an itkImage?

Tags: c++, itk, cimg

I have a CImg image (with double values) with the following form in c++:

```
CImg<double> image(512,512);
Tcyl.fill(1);
```

I would like to use ITK functionality to transform this image. So I need to transform this CImg image into itkImage object. How can I convert?

Comment: This should help... https://stackoverflow.com/q/26584208/2836621 If not, post your code and say which aspect doesn't work correctly.

Comment: Thanks I will try. The function takes CImg <uchar> as a parameter. I need to convert my CImg <double> to CImg <uchar>?

Comment: If your **CImg** contains `double`s, you can get a pointer to the start of them using `image.data()`

Comment: If performance is not absolutely critical, just create your ITK image the same size and write two nested loops copying from CImg to ITK image and improve the speed later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used **ITK** before, so this was a learning curve. Anyway, I managed to make a radial gradient of floats in **CImg** and convert that to an **ITK** image and then write that as a float `TIFF`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#define cimg_display 0
#include "CImg.h"
#include "itkImage.h"
#include "itkImportImageFilter.h"
#include "itkImageFileWriter.h"
#include "itkTIFFImageIO.h"

using namespace cimg_library;
using namespace std;

#define W       512
#define H       512

int main() {
    // Create and initialise float image with radial gradient
   cimg_library::CImg<float> img(W,H); 
   cimg_forXY(img,x,y) {img(x,y) = hypot((float)(W/2-x),(float)(H/2-y)); }

   // Now convert CImg image to ITK image
   const unsigned int Dimension = 2;
   typedef itk::Image<float,Dimension>             InputImageType;
   typedef itk::ImportImageFilter<float,Dimension> ImportFilterType;
   ImportFilterType::Pointer importFilter = ImportFilterType::New();

   InputImageType::SizeType imsize;
   imsize[0] = img.width();
   imsize[1] = img.height();

   ImportFilterType::IndexType start;
   start.Fill(0);
   ImportFilterType::RegionType region;
   region.SetIndex(start);
   region.SetSize(imsize);
   importFilter->SetRegion(region);

   const itk::SpacePrecisionType origin[Dimension] = {0.0,0.0};
   importFilter->SetOrigin(origin);

   const itk::SpacePrecisionType spacing[Dimension] = {1.0,1.0};
   importFilter->SetSpacing(spacing);

   // Tell ITK importFilter to take pixels directly from CImg's buffer
   importFilter->SetImportPointer(img.data(),imsize[0]*imsize[1],false);

   // Write result as a TIFF - so I can check it worked
   typedef itk::ImageFileWriter<InputImageType> WriterType;
   typedef itk::TIFFImageIO                  TIFFIOType;
   TIFFIOType::Pointer tiffIO = TIFFIOType::New();
   tiffIO->SetPixelType(itk::ImageIOBase::SCALAR);
   WriterType::Pointer writer = WriterType::New();
   writer->SetFileName("result.tif");
   writer->SetInput(importFilter->GetOutput());
   writer->SetImageIO(tiffIO);
   writer->Update();
}
```

And here's the result (converted to JPEG for SO):

[image]

It works just the same if you change `float` for `double` except you can't write `double`s to a TIFF so the last bit won't work.

---

I've been messing around some more and managed to load the pixels into a new ITK image ready for further processing, rather than for output:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#define cimg_display 0
#include "CImg.h"
#include "itkImage.h"
#include "itkImageRegionIterator.h"

using namespace cimg_library;
using namespace std;

#define W 5
#define H 3

int main() {
    // Create and initialise double image with simple formula
   cimg_library::CImg<double> img(W,H); 
   cimg_forXY(img,x,y) {img(x,y) = (double)x+(10.0*(double)y); }

   // Now convert CImg image to ITK image
   const unsigned int Dimension = 2;
   typedef itk::Image<double,2> ImageType;
   ImageType::Pointer image = ImageType::New();

   ImageType::SizeType size;
   size[0] = img.width();
   size[1] = img.height();

   ImageType::IndexType start;
   start.Fill(0);

   ImageType::RegionType region;
   region.SetSize(size);
   region.SetIndex(start);
   image->SetRegions(region);
   image->Allocate();

   double origin[2];
   origin[0]=0;
   origin[1]=0;
   image->SetOrigin(origin);

   double spacing[2];
   spacing[0]=1;
   spacing[1]=1;
   image->SetSpacing(spacing);

   typedef itk::ImageRegionIterator<ImageType> IteratorType;
   IteratorType it(image,region);
   it.GoToBegin();

   const double* data = img.data();
   while(!it.IsAtEnd()){
      it.Set(*data);
      ++it;
      ++data;
   }

  // Display pixels for checking purposes
  for(unsigned int r = 0; r < H; r++)
  {
      for(unsigned int c = 0; c < W; c++)
      {
          ImageType::IndexType pixelIndex;
          pixelIndex[0] = c;
          pixelIndex[1] = r;
          ImageType::PixelType      pixelValue = image->GetPixel( pixelIndex );
          cout << "Image[" << r << "," << c << "]: " << pixelValue << endl; 
      }
  }
}
```

**Sample Output**

```
Image[0,0]: 0
Image[0,1]: 1
Image[0,2]: 2
Image[0,3]: 3
Image[0,4]: 4
Image[1,0]: 10
Image[1,1]: 11
Image[1,2]: 12
Image[1,3]: 13
Image[1,4]: 14
Image[2,0]: 20
Image[2,1]: 21
Image[2,2]: 22
Image[2,3]: 23
Image[2,4]: 24
```